# Conda and conda-forge to install commands available from all conda environments

Tags: mercurial, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

I'd like to install programs with conda in one particular conda environment and to be able to use the associated commands from all conda environments.

My goal is to allow students to install Mercurial (plus few Mercurial extensions and related utilities like Meld and TortoiseHg) on any platforms (especially Windows) **with one simple command** (or few simple commands), and of course without compilation.

Of course the `hg` command should be available in the terminal from any conda environments (anaconda prompt on Windows). The Mercurial packages cannot be installed in the base environment because Mercurial still works better in Python 2.7 (anyway, it wouldn't be clean).

Now Mercurial and the extensions we need can be installed on all platforms with something like:

```
conda create -n py27_mercurial -c conda-forge python=2.7 mercurial dulwich ipaddress
conda activate py27_mercurial
pip install hg-evolve hg-git
```

Working a bit with conda-forge and a conda meta-package, it won't be difficult to do that with one very simple command. Moreover, it should not be difficult to create conda packages for Meld and TortoiseHg.

From this stage, the `hg` command is available when the environment is activated (and it is very simple to install other Mercurial extensions). To make it available from other environment (and in the base environment), one need to append the path of the directory containing `hg` to the environment variable PATH or on Unix to create a symbolic link (I don't know Windows enough to know if something similar would work). Both solutions are not straightforward and the commands are not platform independent.

I didn't find a command to do something like this in conda but sometimes conda experts are able to do impressive things! What would be an elegant solution to this issue?

It would also be nice to create icons somewhere (in the Anaconda launcher?) for the graphical applications (Meld and TortoiseHg). Is it possible?

### Edit: Conda applications

I discovered that there is a way to specify in the meta.yaml file that a package is an application: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#app-section

It may help to solve the issue.

### Edit after a first answer based on a bash function:

Of course, I'm looking for a solution involving very small work (and understanding) for the users and with cross-platform commands.

Note that for Linux and Bash, one can just do:

```
CONDA_APP_DIR=$HOME/.local/bin/bin-conda-app/
mkdir -p $CONDA_APP_DIR
echo -e "\nexport PATH=\$PATH:$CONDA_APP_DIR\n" >> ~/.bashrc
ln -s $(which hg) $CONDA_APP_DIR/hg
```

No need to activate/deactivate the environment each time `hg` is used...

Of course, such solutions dependent of the system and the shell are not satisfactory. It should be possible to do such things with cross-platform conda-like commands (see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8556), something like

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install conda-app
conda-app install mercurial
```

Now, I just have to implement `conda-app`

Answer (score 0):

One can always create a shell function/alias and shove it in their shell's runtime configuration file. For example, for your use case, I'd add the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
hg() {
   (conda activate py27_mercurial
    command hg "$@"
    _hg_exit_code=$?
    conda deactivate
    exit $_hg_exit_code)
}
```

Then, regardless of which environment you are in, you always run hg from the environment it was installed in. To make sure that this function is loaded for you shell in a new session, one can always take a look at the output for: `type -a hg`

I do this one-time-setup for all the tools (some are custom compiled) and have an alias/shell function for each. This way I can happily switch b/w environments without having to worry much.

Comment: Interesting but this solution is highly platform dependent (valid only for Unix and Bash) and the users need to modify by hand a configuration file. I'm going to expand the question to give a similar and simpler solution based on symbolic links.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you assume that symlinks will always work. There can be cases where the binary requires config files relative to it, or it loads up external libraries and computes the path to them based on it's current location and it could be the case that these computations do not follow the symlink. It's rare, but possible.

Comment: Ok. Good to know!

Comment: Another problem of your solution based on bash function, it assumes that conda is in the PATH at runtime so it cannot be used in other cases, for example with pyenv.

Comment: With Conda >=4.4, 'conda' a shell function which you can source and not always have the base environment activated by default.

Comment: I reinstall miniconda and conda is a python file $HOME/miniconda3/condabin/conda. So it's true that it can be used even when  $HOME/miniconda3/bin is not in PATH.

Comment: I wonder about the performance cost of your function. I'll have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900964/1779806 is buggy for scripts using `command hg ...` and too inefficient for this case (installation of a command-line application). See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8556#issuecomment-488703716

I created a tiny Python package conda-app (https://pypi.org/project/conda-app/) to improve this situation.

This should now works on Unix systems (with Bash and Fish):

```
conda activate base
conda config --add channels conda-forge
pip install conda-app
conda-app install mercurial
```

It should not be difficult to improve `conda-app` to also support Windows.

For the time being, Windows users can install Mercurial and important extensions by installing [TortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).